# Visual Studio: Open scripts in different window via double click

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, text-editor, double-click, project-explorer

My layout in Visual Studio 2017 is divided into 3 sections:

- Menus on the top
- Project Explorer on the very left
- Text Editor taking up the rest of the screen

When I double click on a class/script in the Project Explorer, it opens it within the same window (simply creates a second tab) and I have to move the tab to the Text Editor window every time.

Is there a way to make a double click open the script in the Text Editor (= another window)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Project Explorer window is Docked as Tabbed Document. In this case, right click the Project Explorer tab and select **Dock** to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's tabbed, the other tab is the "TODO" list. Clicking on "Dock" expanded it over the whole width of my screen and made it its own window that I can't change the size of and that lies over the text editor window.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio

Comment: That's what I did initially: I docked it by dragging the window to the left side. I now closed all of the windows/tabs, reopened them after a restart and dragged them into position. It doesn't look any different but now it actually opens the files in the text editor, so no idea what went wrong the first time.